# Citing a translator

Tags: biblatex

How do I cite a translator as making an interpretative assumption?  If I write
`\cite{taylor}`, the name of the original author will appear, but I want the
name of the translator.

Comment: Can you create a second bib entry, this time with the name of the translator in the `author` field?

Comment: @Mico, I could, but that seems inelegant; I would rather write the name
manually and use `\nocite`.  Or maybe not, I'll think about it.

Comment: You may want to provide a bit more information about what's going on, including *why* you wish to cite the translator in addition to -- or maybe even instead of? -- the original author. For instance, has the translator provided some thoughts or claims which you wish to cite, and are these thoughts separate from and/or in addition to any thoughts and claims expressed by the author of the original work? If so, the translator's contributions are an original piece in their own right, and it's entirely OK (and, in fact, proper!) to cite the translator's separately from the (original) author's work.

Comment: Would using `biblatex` be an option for you?

Comment: @samcarter, yes, I think I already am.

Comment: @Toothrot Great! In biblatex thats easy. Can you just tell us with which options you load the package?

Comment: @Mico, you may be right, even though it seems a bit odd to have two entries for
one book.  In the particular case that occasioned my question the translation
assumes a certain antecedent of a pronoun that might be taken to refer
differently, so, yes, my intention is to cite the translator and not the
author.

Comment: @samcarter, sure: \usepackage[backend=bibtex,giveninits=true,style=authoryear-ibid
 ]{biblatex}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Please read [Mico's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381615/citing-a-translator/381637?noredirect=1#comment945691_381637) first, the following answer just shows the technical possibility to do this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{aristotle:physics,
    options    = {useauthor=false,usetranslator=true},
  author       = {Aristotle},
  title        = {Physics},
  date         = 1929,
  translator   = {Wicksteed, P. H. and Cornford, F. M.},
  publisher    = {G. P. Putnam},
  location     = {New York},
  keywords     = {primary},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  shorttitle   = {Physics},
  annotation   = {A \texttt{book} entry with a \texttt{translator} field},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[backend=bibtex,giveninits=true,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{aristotle:physics}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: usetranslator, neat, thanks.  I wonder if this option can be used on a per citation basis as well.  (Though in reality there may not be much use for that.)

Comment: @Toothrot Probably possible by declaring a new cite command. Search for `\DeclareCiteCommand`

Comment: +1. Readers might find it a tad unusual to see the book entitled *Physics* be associated with a specific pair of English-language translators rather than with the piece's author (Aristotle). If it's really necessary to cite Mssrs. Wicksteed and Cornford, it surely must be because of some pertinent thoughts they expressed in, say, the "Translators' Preface" to *Physics* or in some footnote in which they expounded on some particular challenge to translating an expression from classical Greek to modern English. Using the `@incollection` entry type for their work might be the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Other options using 'note' and 'annotation' fields are described here; [BibTeX: citing both translation and the original](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19703/bibtex-citing-both-translation-and-the-original)

Comment: Could you Make your answer elaborate?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain your answer better. Suppose the given link is broken your answer at the moment is useless ... How does it solve the given issue?